# Java - Recursively alternate colors in circle

Tags: java, recursion, graphics, geometry

How would I go about modifying my current code for a checker board so that the checker pieces recursively alternate in color? Just to be clear, I don't want each piece to be a solid color - I want them to have levels that alternate in color in on itself. So for example, the currently yellow pieces would change to being yellow and blue pieces, having an outer level of yellow, followed by a level of blue, then yellow, etc. I hope that makes sense? I don't believe I can highlight code, but the checker pieces start after the first nested for statement in the checkerBoard method. There are 2 cases, the first being the top 2 rows, and the second being the bottom two.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Checkerboard extends Applet 
{    
   private final int DIST = 100;
   private final int SIZE = 1000;

   public void checkerBoard(int row, int col, int x, int y, boolean b, Graphics g) 
   {    
      for ( row = 0;  row < 8;  row++ ) 
      {         
         for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++) 
         {
            x = col * 100;
            y = row * 100;
            if ( (row % 2) == (col % 2) )
               g.setColor(Color.black);
            else
               g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 100, 100);
         }
      }

      for ( row = 0;  row < 2;  row++ ) 
      {         
         for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++) 
         {
            x = col * 100;
            y = row * 100;
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
         }
      }

      for ( row = 7;  row > 5;  row-- ) 
      {         
         for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++) 
         {
            x = col * 100;
            y = row * 100;
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 100, 100);
         }
      }
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
    checkerBoard(0, 0, 0, 0, true, g);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

is this what you want

```
for ( row = 0;  row < 2;  row++ ) 
  {         
     for ( col = 0;  col < 8;  col++) 
     {
     for ( int ring = 0;  ring < 5;  ring++) {
        x = col * 100 + (ring * 10);
        y = row * 100 + (ring * 10);
        if((ring & 1) == 0){
          g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        }else{
          g.setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        g.fillOval(x, y, 100-(ring*20), 100-(ring*20));
        }
     }
  }
```

recursive method would be like,

```
private void drawCircle(int x, int y, int circleSize, int ringSize, Color primary, Color alternate, Graphics g){
    if(circleSize > 0){
        g.setColor(primary);
        g.fillOval(x, y, circleSize,circleSize);
        drawCircle(x+ringSize/2,y+ringSize/2,circleSize-ringSize,ringSize,alternate,primary, g);
    }
}



for ( row = 0;  row < 2;  row++ ) 
  {         
     for ( col = 0;  col < 4;  col++) 
     {
       int y = row * 100;
       int x = ((col * 2) + (col & 1)) * 100; // want to alternate squares
       drawCircle(x, y, 100, 20, Color.Yellow, Color.Blue,g);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Almost. I need to do it recursively, so I want to call checkerBoard() - though would it make more sense to create a new method and call that one? Also the example you provided was a _bit_ off. Loading it into the applet provided what looked like 3D traffic cones instead of circles alternating in on itself. Maybe they look a bit more like pawns? Amusing if anything. Even when you mess up, graphics are always fun :)

Comment: oops I had my coefficients off. I think these are correct.

Comment: So if I used a new method like you're suggesting, how should I preserve the original nested for statements that made it so the circles were only in the first two and last two rows of the board? Sorry if I'm a little noobish :( - also, it looks like you forgot "Graphics g" in your drawCircle method?

Comment: Keeps getting closer and closer, I'm going to try and work it out from here, but from what I can tell from your code, is that the nested for statements are on the outside of the drawCircle method. Putting it into the drawCircle method wouldn't work out since col and row are missing. I had a similar problem when I started (row and col didn't really fit into the recursive stuff). I really do appreciate the help though!

Comment: Ah! I see what you did. You're trying to preserve the two rows with your nested for loop. Can you explain how you did it? I'm a bit confused on how it works. Also, The way it runs right now is that it prints the first two in the first column, skips the 4 in the next 2 columns, prints 4 in the next 2, skips for in the next 2, then prints 2 in the last column. I'm sure modifying it won't be nearly as difficult though.          Edit: Got it working! I'm unsure why you alternated the squares, but going back to what I originally had (row*100, col*100, & changed the col < 4 to col <8) did the trick!